# Eclipse CDT macro awareness in assembler files

Tags: assembly, macros, eclipse-cdt, code-completion

Currently I am using Eclipse (3.5.x and 3.7.x) with the CDT plugin for several projects that contain besides .c and .h files also .S files with x86 (or IA64) assembler code.

The problem is, that in the .S files a lot of preprocessor macros are used. These macros are typically defined in .h files that are included in the .S file. A contrived example might be

```
#define FOO(regA, regB) \
    mov regA, %ax \
    mov %ax, regB
```

as part of header1.h

Then foo.S might contain

```
#include "header1.h"
...
FOO(%bx, %cx)
...
```

What is missing now is the possibility when one is editing foo.S to jump with F3 to the definition of FOO in header1.h or (what apparently is connected with this) to see a preview of the macro expansio.

I can do this from inside .c (or .h) files, but not from .S files. Is there a way to enable this functionality for .S files too?